# TFS task queue endpoint

Tags: tfs

I am building an UWP for Windows 10 so I have to wrap the TFS API myself. That works fine but I just can't get the queue API to work.

My code calls this URL: http://192.168.2.128:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/justatest/_apis/distributedtask/queues?api-version=3.0-preview.1

But it returns a 404. Do you know an endpoint that is not preview and so is available in TFS 2015?

Comment: What update of TFS 2015 are you on?

Comment: Update 3 most recent version.

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce your issue if use similar URL as yours: http://xxx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/***teamproject***/_apis/distributedtask/queues?api-version=3.0-preview.1

Remove ***teamproject*** will solve this issue. The URL should look like:

```
http://xxx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/distributedtask/queues?api-version=3.0-preview.1
```